# Check Default Radio Button

Tags: vb.net, enums, radio-button

I am building a Tic Tac Toe game and I came across some trouble when I was trying to select the Radio Button that the variable states. Heres my code:

```
'Level Selection Enum
Public Enum GameDifficulty

    optEasy = 0
    optMedium = 1
    optHard = 2
    optTest = 3
End Enum

'Default Level
Public SelectedGameDifficulty As GameDifficulty = GameDifficulty.optTest
```

What I am trying to do is select the radio button that the variable SelectedGameDifficulty states but I don't know how. The radio buttons are located on the form and the names for the radio buttons are optEasy, optMedium, optHard, and optTest. Can anybody help me?

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or what else?

Comment: WinForms. It's a really simple Tic Tac Toe game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add all of your radio buttons inside a control array and convert the Enum variable to an integer to index the correct RadioButton and check it

```
Dim controls() as RadioButton = {optEasy, optMedium, optHard, optTest}
controls(CType(SelectedGameDifficulty, Integer)).Checked = True
```

Of course this scheme works because the RadioButtons are added inside the array in such a way that they have an order matching the integer value of the associated Enum.